# How to query for time period based on another time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with two columns (StartDate & EndDate) with these records:

```
StartDate                     EndDate
2019-03-21 02:00:00.0000000   2019-03-23 04:00:00.0000000
2019-03-22 02:00:00.0000000   2019-03-23 05:00:00.0000000
2019-03-22 07:00:00.0000000   2019-03-22 12:00:00.0000000
2019-03-22 01:00:00.0000000   2019-03-23 04:00:00.0000000
```

I also receive from my application two custom dates:

start_date = '2019-03-22 00:00:00'

end_date = '2019-03-22 23:59:59'

I have already tried with the following query, but it's not returning all the records that fit:

```
select * from [dbo].[Bookings]
where (StartDate <= '2019-03-22 00:00:00' AND EndDate >= '2019-03-22 23:59:59')
OR (StartDate >= '2019-03-22 00:00:00' AND EndDate <= '2019-03-22 23:59:59')
```

I want to return all records that fit (or are inside) this received time period, which in this case, should be all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post, I take 'fit' to mean that they are active at some point between the start and end date, as you indicated all four records should be in there.  You need to switch around the matchings for the start and end dates

```
select * from dbo.Bookings 
where end_date >= '2019-03-22 00:00:00' -- records finish after custom start
and start_date <= '2019-03-22 23:59:59' -- but do not start beyond your desired window.
```

Comment: Worked for all my situations, thank you very much for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

change the condition in where clause

```
    select a.* from [dbo].[Bookings] a
    where StartDate >= '2019-03-22 00:00:00' AND EndDate <= '2019-03-22 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but it's not working. It's just returning one record and it should return all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you generically want overlaps.  The logic for this is:

```
select b.*
from [dbo].[Bookings] b
where b.StartDate < '2019-03-23' AND
      b.EndDate >= '2019-03-22'
```

Notice that I simplified the datetime logic so you don't have to worry about the time component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
         DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2019-03-22 00:00:00.000' , @Endate DATETIME= '2019-03-22 23:59:59.999'

 select a.* from [dbo].[tt] a 
 Where ( startDate <= @date or 
 EndDate>=@Endate)
 Union All 
 select a.* from [dbo].[tt] a 
 where StartDate >= @date AND EndDate <= @Endate
```

Comment: Also a nice solution that worked, thank you very much!